# SwiftUI faulty animation running simultaneously with keyboard dismissal

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple "raised label textfield", where the label is raised if the textfield is focused or containing a value.

If the keyboard dismisses and the label is lowered (meaning that the textfield has no value), the label will animate to its final position with the SwiftUI  given position, but the textfield position will animate alongside the keyboard animation.

This is only a problem when the textfield aint placed in a scrollview, but I would like it to not be a problem at all.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct RaisedLabelTextField2: View {

    @State private var value = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused

    private var raiseLabel: Bool { !value.isEmpty || isFocused }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $value)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .background(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Text("Label 2")
                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { d in
                        raiseLabel ? d.height : 0
                    }
            }
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: raiseLabel)
    }
}

struct RaisedLabelTextField1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RaisedLabelTextField2()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So ... trying just every positional modifier out there ... I found a fix.
Simply adding a identity transformation fixes it.

```
.transformEffect(.identity)
```